# How to find similar pattern from time series with distance?

Tags: python, deep-learning, data-science, sequence

I have a dataset like this

| a_1 | ab_1 | b_1 | bc_1 | c_1 | ac_1 | a_2 | ab_2 | b_2 | bc_2 | c_2 | ac_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| -100.0 | 1 | -200.0 | 1 | 0.0 | 2 | -200.0 | 1 | -100.0 | 1 | -200.0 | 2 |
| 0.0 | 2 | 0.0 | 3 | 100.0 | 5 | 0.0 | 2 | 0.0 | 3 | 0.0 | 5 |
| -100.0 | 4 | -100.0 | 2 | -100.0 | 6 | -100.0 | 4 | 0.0 | 2 | -100.0 | 6 |
| 100.0 | 2 | 0.0 | 3 | 100.0 | 5 | 0.0 | 2 | 0.0 | 3 | 0.0 | 5 |
| -100.0 | 3 | -100.0 | 3 | -200.0 | 6 | 0.0 | 3 | 0.0 | 3 | -100.0 | 6 |
| 0.0 | 1 | 0.0 | 4 | 0.0 | 5 | -100.0 | 1 | -100.0 | 4 | 0.0 | 5 |
| 0.0 | 2 | 0.0 | 1 | 0.0 | 3 | 0.0 | 2 | 0.0 | 1 | 0.0 | 3 |
| 0.0 | 3 | -100.0 | 2 | -200.0 | 5 | -100.0 | 3 | -200.0 | 2 | -200.0 | 5 |
| 0.0 | 2 | -100.0 | 2 | 0.0 | 4 | 0.0 | 2 | -200.0 | 2 | -100.0 | 4 |
| 200.0 | 4 | 0.0 | 2 | 0.0 | 6 | 200.0 | 4 | 0.0 | 2 | 0.0 | 6 |

or this is the csv format

```
a_1, ab_1, b_1, bc_1, c_1, ac_1, a_2, ab_2, b_2, bc_2, c_2, ac_2
-100.0,1,-200.0,1,0.0,2,-200.0,1,-100.0,1,-200.0,2
0.0,2,0.0,3,100.0,5,0.0,2,0.0,3,0.0,5
-100.0,4,-100.0,2,-100.0,6,-100.0,4,0.0,2,-100.0,6
100.0,2,0.0,3,100.0,5,0.0,2,0.0,3,0.0,5
-100.0,3,-100.0,3,-200.0,6,0.0,3,0.0,3,-100.0,6
0.0,1,0.0,4,0.0,5,-100.0,1,-100.0,4,0.0,5
0.0,2,0.0,1,0.0,3,0.0,2,0.0,1,0.0,3
0.0,3,-100.0,2,-200.0,5,-100.0,3,-200.0,2,-200.0,5
0.0,2,-100.0,2,0.0,4,0.0,2,-200.0,2,-100.0,4
200.0,4,0.0,2,0.0,6,200.0,4,0.0,2,0.0,6
```

as we can see, we have:

a : onset value / starting point value
b : apex value / peak value
c : offset value / finish point value
ab : distance a to b
bc : distance b to c
ac : distance a to c or `ab + bc`

and i have a data like this

```py
line1 = [-100, 0 , 100, -100,-200,0,0,100,100,-100]
line2 = [0, 100 , 100, -200,-100,-100,0,100,100,-100]
```

by this series pattern, it **almost** similar with:

| a_1 | ab_1 | b_1 | bc_1 | c_1 | ac_1 | a_2 | ab_2 | b_2 | bc_2 | c_2 | ac_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| -100.0 | 1 | -200.0 | 1 | 0.0 | 2 | -200.0 | 1 | -100.0 | 1 | -200.0 | 2 |

why almost? because in line2 there is some different

[0, 100 , 100, -200,-100,***-100***,0,100,100,-100]

so we can see in plot like this

[image: plot sequence]

how to find the similar or almost similar pattern in dataset?

Comment: We cannot see!!!  Your data doesn't have any of the variables you mention (i.e. a,  b,  c,  ab, or bc).  Please clarify your logic